# POST to mongoose DB with Nested schema

Tags: database, object, mongoose, post, schema

I have an inventory schema with item subschema as below:

```
const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    name: { //Full name of product
        type: String,
    },
    type: { //Beer? Wine? Liquor? Cider?
        type: String,
    },
    unit: { //What is the minimum amount you can order? 
        type: Number,
    },
    volume: { //How much liquid is in it?(in mL)
        type: Number,
    },
    packaging: {
        type: String,
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
    },   
},
{
    timestamps: true,
}

const InventorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    user: { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: [true, 'Need user ID'],
        ref: 'User'
    },
    items: {
        type: [ItemSchema],
        default: []
    }
},
{
    timestamps: true,
}
```

I am building an API to add subschema Item, but how do I do it?

```
const addItem = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
//req.user.id is given by authentication middleware
//req.body is the ItemSchema object
if (!req.user.id) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error('Cannot add without ID')
}
const newItem = {
    user: req.user.id,
    items: await ItemModel.create(req.body),
}

res.status(200).send(newItem)
```

This is what I have ATM, but I don't think I am doing it right. I get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')" response.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
When creating a schema, if you only have a regular type, just write the types, no need for all the overheads-

```
const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: String,
 type: {type: String},
 unit: Number... etc..
}
```

also, arrays default value are empty arrays so you don't need to tell this to mongoose. so you can just do in your InventorySchema:

```
items:[ItemSchema]
```

regarding your question,
First, you need to create Models out of your schemas.
So for example:

```
const InventoryModel = new mongoose.model('Inventory', InventorySchema);
```

and also do it for the item schema

and then create a new item from it, and in your controller:

```
...
...
const newItem = new ItemModel({....});
const newInventory = new InventoryModel({user: req.user.id,});
newInventory.items.push(newItem);
newInventory.save(); 
...
...
```

Than the new inventory is saved in your DB and you can do whatever you want with it

Comment: Thanks for the help! but if I try to push a newItem with existing objectID(so the item is already in items), what happens? Ideally I would want it to update the existing object instead of adding new object. Would I need to iterate through objects and POST upon finding matching _id, or will the database do it for me?

Comment: @Steve I hope I understand your question correctly - 
You created the InventorySchema with items attribute which is embedded! and not referenced like the user attribute (which is by objectId)
Because it is embedded it exist inside the document. this is why in the example I created a new item and pushed it. I did not look for existing and pushed them.
if you want you can make it by reference and than pushing the _id of the existing item.

Sorry if I don't get you correctly, try to explain yourself again